# A transitive subgroup of $S_n$ containing a p-cycle with $\frac n2<p<n-2$ is $S_n$ or $A_n$

Tags: galois-theory, symmetric-groups

The following result may help to determine the Galois group of an irreducible  polynomial.

Theorem : Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ and p a prime number in $]\frac n2;n-2[$. If $G$ contains a p-cycle then G is either $S_n$ or $A_n$.

Does somebody have a comprehensive proof of this fact ? Using basic arguments, please. References are wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a reference, Coleman uses this exact result in his [paper about Galois groups of exponential polynomials](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=ens-001:1987:33::61#316). I haven't seen the proof yet, but he cites Marshall Hall's 1959 edition of 'The Theory of Groups', Theorems 5.6.2 and 5.7.2.